# android xml file modifying

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I receive a `XML` string from server that is structured like this:

```
<item_list>
    <category>
        <item id="1" name="name1" base64="base64String1" />
        <item id="2" name="name2" base64="base64String2" />
        <item id="3" name="name3" base64="base64String3" />
        <item id="4" name="name4" base64="base64String4" />
        ........
    </category>
    <category>
    ........
    </category>
<item_list>
```

What I need to do is this: when I first read the string, read the `Base64` strings, save them in a file and then remove them from this string. And then write this string to a `XML` file. So after that this `XML` will look like:

```
<item_list>
    <category>
        <item id="1" name="name1" />
        <item id="2" name="name2" />
        <item id="3" name="name3" />
        <item id="4" name="name4" />
        ........
    </category>
    <category>
    ........
    </category>
<item_list>
```

Which parser show I use for reading and deleting the `Base64` strings? which is the best for this?

And if someone could give me an example or a tutorial how to do this, it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You can use XPath for that with the expression query "//*[@base64]".

```
try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(new File("your_xml.xml"));

            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            String expression = "//*[@base64]";

            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expression, document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
                String base64 = element.getAttribute("base64");
                element.removeAttribute("base64");
            }

            String newXML = getStringFromNode(document);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

getStringFromNode method

```
public static String getStringFromNode(Node root) {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        if (root.getNodeType() == 3)
            result.append(root.getNodeValue());
        else { 
            if (root.getNodeType() != 9) {
                StringBuffer attrs = new StringBuffer();
                for (int k = 0; k < root.getAttributes().getLength(); ++k) {
                    attrs.append(" ").append(
                            root.getAttributes().item(k).getNodeName()).append(
                            "=\"").append(
                            TextUtils.htmlEncode(root.getAttributes().item(k).getNodeValue()))
                            .append("\" ");
                }
                result.append("<").append(root.getNodeName()).append(" ")
                        .append(attrs).append(">");
            } else {
                result.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
            }

            NodeList nodes = root.getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0, j = nodes.getLength(); i < j; i++) {
                Node node = nodes.item(i);
                result.append(getStringFromNode(node));
            }

            if (root.getNodeType() != 9) {
                result.append("</").append(root.getNodeName()).append(">");
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
```

**EDITED**

The same could be used for parsing the String also. See my method below which will parse the String as DOM Document. Now you can use this Document as input for your XPath.

```
public static Document ReadDocument(String xml)
    {
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
            is.setCharacterStream(reader);
            doc = db.parse(is); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", "Error while Parsing Document", e);
            return null;
        }
        return doc;
    }
```

Comment: If I understood well, this way I'm reading the content from file, modifying it, and transforming it into String. What I need is read a string that has content like XML, then modify it, and write it into XML file. What I get from the server is String, not file.

Comment: So I should make Document object from the string I receive, and then edit it like you wrote in the first place, right? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Minor improvements for Vivek's function -> Handle CDATA + Use field constants:

```
public static String getStringFromNode(Node root) throws IOException 
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    if (root.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE)
        result.append(root.getNodeValue());
    else if(root.getNodeType() == Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE)
        result.append("<![CDATA["+root.getNodeValue()+"]]>");
    else {
        if (root.getNodeType() != Node.DOCUMENT_NODE) {
            StringBuffer attrs = new StringBuffer();

            for (int k = 0; k < root.getAttributes().getLength(); ++k) {
                attrs.append(" ").append(
                        root.getAttributes().item(k).getNodeName()).append(
                        "=\"").append(
                        root.getAttributes().item(k).getNodeValue())
                        .append("\" ");
            }
            result.append("<").append(root.getNodeName()).append(" ")
                    .append(attrs).append(">");
        } else {
            result.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
        }

        NodeList nodes = root.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0, j = nodes.getLength(); i < j; i++) {
            Node node = nodes.item(i);
            result.append(getStringFromNode(node));
        }

        if (root.getNodeType() != Node.DOCUMENT_NODE) {
            result.append("</").append(root.getNodeName()).append(">");
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```